# How to handle too quick edit approvals

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

When I review edits I think I'm rather picky. I just verified that I have rejected 37% of all suggested edits I reviewed so far, usually for the following reasons:

- The editor fixes few spelling mistakes in a question/answer that should be completely rewritten to make sense (too minor).
- The editor tries to format code but fails miserably. For instance, he adds brackets that change the meaning of the code (invalid edit).
- The editor adds one or two tags that nobody cares about (too minor).

In these obvious cases I can just click the rejection reason "in time". Sometimes the reason why the edit should be rejected is more subtle and I want to type a custom reason. I have noticed, however, that in those cases I'm always "too late" (even when I take only 15 seconds longer) because the edit was approved already before I can even click reject.

As I said, the reason why the edit should be rejected is more subtle in these cases, so I can understand that some others approve. But to me it is frustrating that I take the time to do these reviews seriously and my vote is just ignored. Of course, I can go to the post and do the edit manually, but I feel that the system could benefit from some improvement here.

As a simple proposal I could imagine that the review process is not closed until all reviewers that were asked their opinion have actually responded (or after some timeout of course). But maybe someone has a better idea?

Comment: Welcome to the club ...

Comment: Oops, searched for the wrong keywords, so I didn't realize this is a duplicate...